# How to read post url request from javascript in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have form with inputs in html.
Then I added this javascript (jquery) stroke to read and collect all value or data from form.

```
var formData = $("#form").serialize();
```

When I

```
console.log(formData);
```

Output will show:

> calc-ownership=ooo&calc-activity=restaurant&calc-tax=usn&calc-tax-2=charge&calc-bank=partners&calc-who-payments=client&operations_count=0&calc-nomenclature=slim&documents_count=0&calc-who-docs=client&staff_count=0&calc-more%5B%5D=patent&calc-more%5B%5D=alcohol&period=&price=&price_sber=&rate-name=&email-to=

Then I found function in jquery called post
**`$.post(path, formData, success, "json");`**
Request look like:
**do.php?bank=partners**

As you see it makes post request to my `do.php`.
Now how I can read this query and work with this data?

I found analog to `$.post` in jquery. It is `$.ajax`
Full code:

```
$.ajax({ url: path, method: "POST", data: {formData: formData} });
```

It works well.
But I want to work with `$.post`

I am looking at my url at the moment. And it looks : `https://stackoverflow.com?ask=32321`

I need something similar to read my query from javascript this url with php

Comment: Can you explain that further? If the current request is based on a `POST` request, the form's data is not sent back to the browser

Comment: @Nico Haase I mean
it makes request to my php which looks like
**http://localhost/intercompforme2/do.php?calc-ownership=ooo**

Then how php reads this query? to work them. For ex. write in txt file

Comment: I've read your question a couple of times now but I still have no idea what your actual question is. Instead of showing us a line of code here and there, please show us _all_ the relevant code in it's correct context.

Comment: The problem is that you¨'re not making a POST request, you're making a GET request. If you want your ajax request to be POST,  it's `type: 'POST'`, not `method="POST"`.

Comment: Well, PHP "reads the query" into the `$_GET` and `$_POST` variables. You can use these however you like, but not using jQuery

Comment: I mean jquery makes request like **do.php?calc-ownership=ooo**
So How my php can read this request and parse values?

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson you mean
`$.ajax({ url: path, type: "POST", data: {formData: formData} });`

Comment: @Cengez - I've posted an answer with examples.

Comment: all of answers using `$.ajax`
But I need help with `$.post`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I will explain with example,

If you want to get url parameter values to you have to use,

```
<script>
let my_variable='<?php echo $_GET['url_param_name'];?>';
</script>
```

above for more help and understanding. Now you want to send form data to php for processing as I got your answer.

This is sample form.

```
<form id="my_form" name"my_form" method="POST" onsubmit="return send();">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="first_name" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="last_name" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

To post above form I will use javascript function,

```
<script>
function send() {

    $.ajax
    ({
        type: 'POST',
        url: './path/your_php_file_where_form_data_processed.php',
        data:$('#my_form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
           // do what you need to do on succeess
        },
        error: function (x, e) {
            // for error handling
            if (x.status == 0) {
                console.log('You are offline!! -  Please Check Your Network.');
            } else if (x.status == 404) {
                console.log('Requested URL not found.');
            } else if (x.status == 500) {
                console.log('Internal Server Error.');
            } else if (e == 'parsererror') {
                console.log('Error. - Parsing JSON Request failed.');
            } else if (e == 'timeout') {
                console.log('Request Time out.');
            } else {
                console.log('Unknown Error. - ' + x.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
}
</<script>
```

> Now you need to check carefully your form element names. In php file. Let's look it.

```
<?php
//include_once './../../classes/Database.php'; import if you have database configurations
//session_start(); make sure to use sessions if your site using sessions

if(isset($_POST))
{
    var_dump($_POST); //this will echo your form inputed data.
    //if you want use one by one posted data
    echo $_POST['first_name'];
    echo $_POST['last_name'];
}
else
{
    echo 'Data not comes here';
}
?>
```

Thought this might help your task.

Comment: you are using **$.ajax**
I need help with **$.post()**
But Thanks for examples

Comment: As I got your question you need to pass data from frontend to backend using ajax?
If it is use this style. It saved time. Because I develop big projects as this styles and it's easy to handle.

Comment: I don't need **ajax**
I just need to use **$.post**

Comment: @Cengez - `$.post` is just a short version of `$.ajax({type: 'POST'})`. The requests will be _identical_. I've posted some examples and explanations in my answer.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson yes you are right,
if you use ajax you could handle GET and POST http methods by changing type

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson
$.post is just a short version of $.ajax({type: 'POST'})
I didn't know that before. Thanks for the clear explanation

Comment: @Cengez - you should really start reading the documentation for the technologies/libraries you're using: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ clearly states: _"This is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:"_ and then shows a `$.ajax`-request.

Comment: @SashIKa
But why my php $data = $_POST['formData'] ?? ''; $fp = fopen('log.txt', 'w+'); fwrite($fp, $data); doesn't write anything?

Comment: In my example that's why I mentioned to use ```var_dump($_POST);``` Then after you can get idea of form datas and access one by one. As you defined in form element names. If data comes to backend then you can work on file read write thing.

Answer (score 0):

When you see the form elements as a query string, you're not making a POST request, but a GET request.

Change your Ajax code to:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: path, 
    type: "POST", 
    data: formData
});
```

What's changed:

1. I've changed `method: 'POST'` to the correct attribute: `type: 'POST'`, which will make the Ajax request to make a POST request instead of the default GET.
2. Changed `data: {formData: formData}` to just `data: formData`. There's no need to post it as json when you've already serialized the data.

If you rather want to use `$.post`, then use:

```
$.post(path, formData);
```

Just to be clear, both the `$.ajax` and `$.post`-requests above will make *identical* requests.

Now, in your PHP-code, you can access the values like this:

```
$calcOwnership = $_POST['calc-ownership'];
```

...to get the posted data.

I would recommend that you read the documentation about the methods you're using:

- [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
- [Dealing with forms in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)

Comment: But why my php 
```$data = $_POST['formData'] ?? '';
$fp = fopen('log.txt', 'w+');
fwrite($fp, $data);```
doesn't write anything?

Comment: @Cengez - Please don't move the goal post. This is the first time you've mentioned anything about storing anything in a file. This answer answers your question, how to make a post request and how to get the posted data in PHP. If you have some other issue, post a new question. If you want to store the posted data in a file, use: `$data = json_encode($_POST);`. That will serialize the posted data as json.

Answer (score -1):

I may have misunderstood your question, but in php you can take values from post using $_POST['variable_name'].

```
<?php
  $documents_count = $_POST['documents_count']
?>
```

In fact this, in your url is not a query, are variables. sorry if it's not what you asked.

Comment: The OP isn't making a POST request, so the `$_POST`-array will be empty.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
But as I said it works when I replace my `$.post`
with `$.ajax({ url: path, method: "POST", data: {formData: formData} });`
This case works only with **`.ajax**